# Pass by const reference in C

Tags: c++, c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-const-reference

Does C support pass by const reference like C++? If not, are there other ways to make pass-by-value more efficient? I don't think it makes sense to pass references to a function only because it's more efficient.

Comment: In C, use pointers, you will copy only the pointer. `I don't think it makes sense to pass references to a function only because it's more efficient` -> This is very dangerous in C++. If you don't pass a reference, you do an implicit copy. This is very costly and that's why it is recommended to have private copy-constructor.

Comment: The benefit of reference variable is simple to use capable as pointers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C does not support references or passing by reference.  You should use pointers instead and pass by address. Pass-by-value is efficient for primitive types, but does a shallow copy for structs.

In C++ it makes a LOT of sense to pass objects by reference for efficiency.  It can save a ton of copying and calling of constructors/destructors when copy constructors are defined.  For large data objects (such as `std::list`) it is impractical to pass-by-value because the list would be copied when passed.  Here you should definitely pass by reference.

Comment: I would like to clarify then; if I want to pass a struct quickly in C, I should pass by pointer, and use the const keyword if I didn't intend on modifying?